# Refetch Database for Eloquent Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm using eager loading on my Laravel model to get around the N+1 problem. The issue is, I used to reload my model by just doing this again:

```
$login = Login::find(1)->load('someothermodel');
```

but now I found out that when I do this, I get huge memory leaks. So my question is, is there any way I can simply reload the Eloquent model or do I have to ditch eager loading?

I switched over to eager loading since some Logins had more than 100 relations which had an impact on my DB performance.

Comment: How do you know that there are memory leaks ?

Comment: `Out of memory (allocated 330301440) (tried to allocate 2097152 bytes)` and `memory_get_usage(true)`.

Comment: Try $login = Login::with('someothermodel')->find(1);

Comment: Eloquent is not made or suited for handling huge amounts of database rows. `Login::find(1)->someothermodel()->count()` will tell you how many related models that single model has. 100 related models for a single model is probably fine, but if you're loading 100 models with 100 related models each you should probably reconsider your approach.

Comment: It has 89 but it worked perfectly before. The real question is, how do I destroy these related models when reassigning the Login variable to prevent memory leaks.